# Is this a good solution for comparing String to Date?

Tags: java

Ok, I am building app for mobile phone so the app needs to very little memory. In Database I have the string in yyyy-MM-dd format, example "1980-11-17". I also have a list of 121 consecutive dates like this:

```
"1977-12-12", "1978-11-13", "1979-12-14","1980-12-16",...
```

I compare string rather than convert the String to Date.

```
if(yyyyMmDd.compareTo("1977-12-12")>=0 && yyyyMmDd.compareTo("1978-11-13")<=0){
        return 1;
}
else if(yyyyMmDd.compareTo("1979-12-14")<=0){
        return 2;
}
else if(yyyyMmDd.compareTo("1980-12-16")<=0){
        return 3;
}
..... need to do another 119 times
```

The goal is to let the computer to use as little energy as possible. Others may require to convert String to `java Date` but i am not sure if it is better than `compareTo` String

Comment: memory efficiency? use integer timestamps, not strings. "yyyy-mm-dd" uses 10 bytes, an integer timestamp uses 4.

Comment: And if your list of dates is fixed, use a binary search instead of a linear search to greatly reduce your energy use.

Comment: @Mike how to convert "yyyy-mm-dd" to int?

Comment: If "mobile phone" = "android", don't worry about such optimization here (over a whopping 121 items). Make sure to provide more clear/relevant context.

Comment: Furthermore, this is likely "optimizing" the wrong thing. Using an *array* and defined mapping could eliminate almost every if-else statements making the program much *smaller* and easier to maintaine. (1 array/source, 1 loop, and 1-2 if-statements vs. 121+ if-statements..)

Comment: Doing that 122 times is not efficient.  You'd be far better off converting the date to a number (which only needs to be done once) and comparing to numbers in an array, in terms of space efficiency, performance efficiency, and maintainability.  As a general rule, any time you repeat the same sequence more than 4-5 times you should be using arrays and loops.

Comment: As to how to convert, Java has 3-4 different date conversion toolkits (unfortunately, not standardized down to one), and any should be able to do the job.  Or you could cheat and convert "1980-12-16" to "19801216" and then convert that to int/long.